# How do you find multiple matches of a string between two different tokens with python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble creating a regex expression supported by python to handle this use case.

Imagine you have a text string that is a set of questions and multiple choice answers:

```
Question 1: What witch-like attributes do you have?
Answer 1:
x Hat
o Pointy Nose
x Float
x Weigh more than a duck

Question 2: Where could this coconut have come from?
Answer 2:
o It migrated
x A European swallow carried it
o An African swallow carried it
x It doesn't matter
```

... and you would like to parse the above text for only the "x" answers to Question 1 using Regex.

If you had access to PCRE you could do something like this using the \G (last match) anchor:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|Question 1:)(?:(?!Question 1:|Question 2:)[\s\S])*?\K(?:x\s)([a-z]+)(?=(?:(?!Question 1:)[\s\S])*Question 2:)
```

...or maybe even something fun using subroutines (e.g., `(textbetweentokens)(?1)(textwithx)`.

But python doesn't support either of those regex features.

Is there any other way to solving this regex challenge?

Note: There are other questions like this on stackoverflow, but none that I could find that had answers that were usable with python-supported regex.

Comment: Instead of regex, why not use `str.startswith()` for x and o?

Comment: There are lots of other ways to solve it via code...but I was really looking for a regex way to match the other way I was handling parsing in this function.

Comment: Is the matching to the other way vital to the way your program works or is it for consistency? Because a regex approach seems much more cumbersome and difficult to read.

Comment: Not vital, but reads nicer because I have dozens of things to parse so I have a nice structure for looping through the RegEx strings.

Comment: You could use https://pypi.org/project/regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match each line that starts with "x" but include a look-ahead assertion that checks that the next question is question 2:

```
^x\s(.*)(?=\s+(?:^(?!Question).*\s+)*^Question 2)
```

Use the `re.M` flag so `^` matches with the start of a line.

This assumes of course that the question that precedes question 2 is question 1.

```py
import re

s = """Question 1: What witch-like attributes do you have?
Answer 1:
x Hat
o Pointy Nose
x Float
x Weigh more than a duck

Question 2: Where could this coconut have come from?
Answer 2:
o It migrated
x A European swallow carried it
o An African swallow carried it
x It doesn't matter
"""0

answers = re.findall(r"^x\s(.*)(?=\s+(?:^(?!Question).*\s+)*^Question 2)", s, re.M)
print(answers)
```

Output:

```py
['Hat', 'Float', 'Weigh more than a duck']
```

#### Explanations

The `(?!Question)` is a negative look ahead so to avoid that there are intermediate questions before reaching Question 2. For instance, if we actually wanted the answers to question 4, we would look for "Question 5", but we should be sure not to pick up the answers to the first three questions. This negative look ahead assertion will make sure that doesn't happen.

The `(.*)` is the capture group that will be retained in the `findall` results. If you want an answer to have at least one character, then you could change that to `(.+)`, but I guess you either don't have empty answers in your input, or else would like to know about them, so that's why I chose for `(.*)`.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, thanks! What is the purpose of the !Question ? I seem to get the same result if I take that out. Also the star in the capture group should be a plus right?

Comment: I added two paragraphs about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your text to line to use `str.startswith()`

```
texte = """Question 1: What witch-like attributes do you have?
Answer 1:
x Hat
o Pointy Nose
x Float
x Weigh more than a duck

Question 2: Where could this coconut have come from?
Answer 2:
o It migrated
x A European swallow carried it
o An African swallow carried it
x It doesn't matter"""

lines = texte.splitlines()
for l in lines:
    if l.startswith('x'):
        print(l)
```

Output:

```
x Hat
x Float
x Weigh more than a duck
x A European swallow carried it
x It doesn't matter
```